# Access a JSON in Python

Tags: python, json

I'm new at Python as well as JQuery.

I have the next JSON in JS

```
var intervalos= {"variables":{

             "nombreVariables":nombreVariables,
             "extremoInferior":fromarray,
             "extremoSuperior":toarray,
             "step":steparray,
             "random":randomarray
          }};//intervalos
```

I did in Python

```
parsed_input = json.loads(self.intervalos)
```

How can I access to the structure? (I know that this is a list/dictionary)

like this

```
intervalos['variables']['nombreVariables'][i];
```

Comment: Yes, just like this. Did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, the JS is remote. Assuming its accessible at `http://example.com/json` one would import it into python as follows:

```
import requests
parsed_input = requests.get('http://example.com/json').json()
for i in xrange(0, len(parsed_input['variables']['nombreVariables']):
    print parsed_input['variables']['nombreVariables'][i]
```

You'll need [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) to make this work in [python2](https://python.org). With python 3.x, your syntax will be slightly different.